# ERROR: virtualenvwrapper could not create a temporary file name

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, virtualenvwrapper

I installed virtualenvwrapper in the following way:

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

$ brew install python
$ brew install pip
$ pip install virtualenvwrapper

$  nano ~/.bashrc 
# Set architecture flags
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
# Ensure user-installed binaries take precedence
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/share/python:$PATH
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
# Load .bashrc if it exists
test -f ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

I got the following error after I executed `source .bashrc`

```
touch: : No such file or directory
ERROR: virtualenvwrapper could not create a temporary file name.
touch: : No such file or directory
ERROR: virtualenvwrapper could not create a temporary file name.
```

How is it possible to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution:

```
# Set architecture flags
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
# Ensure user-installed binaries take precedence
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/share/python:$PATH

export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv

export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

# Load .bashrc if it exists
#test -f ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```